# wysiwyg-Jquery HTML Editor for grammar check which supports in all browsers

Tags: java, jquery, spring, editor

Have anyone worked on Jquery HTML Editor for grammar check which supports all browsers.I need it urgently for my Java web application.I have been using Kendo UI editor.Kendo UI is super and it supports styling,Formatting etc but not able to find a grammar and spell checker along with it.

I tried with wysiwyg editor demo version but its showing browser issue in chromium.I am not sure whether it is a version isuue?

The demo version of "After the Deadline" control is having grammar check so I downloaded "After the Deadline" control too but am not sure whether I  Can use it as javascript API plugin, without using server side code like PHP, Java,.Net etc.

Regards,
Liby Mathew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a jQuery library available here, which is of course all client-side:"After the Deadline"
http://www.afterthedeadline.com/download.slp?platform=jQuery and it helps in spelling and grammar check.